# JFreeChart: How can I get the exact XYDataItem instance which is pointed by crosshair?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to get the exact instance of `XYDataItem` when a mouse click makes the crosshair lock on the nearest data point, as the picture below shows.

[image: The crosshair now locks on a data point]

Now I am able to get the X-Y position of the crosshair when a mouse click event happens with a `ChartMouseListener`, but it may not be good to get the `XYDataItem` according to the X value and Y value. From the mouse event, another thing is `ChartEntity`, but it is based on where the mouse clicks, not where the crosshair locks on.

So.. Is there any better way to let me do this?
**Or**
if you want to make show a lot of additional data related to the data point each time when the crosshair locks on it, how will you do that? (Now I am extending XYDataItem and adding a new field to the sub class so that I can either put the information directly in it, or put an ID that can help me get the additional data from the data list, and that's why I hope the crosshair can give me the exact data item).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`ChartProgressListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/ChartProgressListener.html). Once drawing has finished, ask the [`XYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) for the domain and range crosshair values. Locate the corresponding value in your `XYDataset`.

Use a tooltip to display data in your chart, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513). You can override `generateLabel()` to add your custom data. Alternatively, update an external component's model, as shown in the miscellaneous [crosshair demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Comment: Thank you trashgod. In `XYSeries`, the only way that I can get a XYDataItem is to use `getDataItem(int index)`, and there is also a function named `indexof(Number x)` which returns the index of the item with the x value, so I should have been able to use this to get the index and then get the item -- however, I can't. There will be a lot of `XYDataItem`s with the same x value in the `XYDataset`, so I assume I will get the index of the first one with the x value when I use indexof -- that is a problem.

Comment: Won't the combination of domain (_x_) and range (_y_) be unique? An an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful.

Comment: The combination will be unique, but `indexof` just has a 'x' as the parameter. I will prepare an sscce with sample data.

Comment: Ah, I see; you may need to do a [full scan](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#line.855) of the model.

Comment: Update: I checked again and I will have to say I can't make sure if the combination could be unique, because the x is revision number in svn and the y is the score of the benchmark test, and I often test one revision for multiple times, thus there may be a same x and y. But if there are two points with the same x and y value, I can just ignore it. But those with same x and different y could not be ignored.

Comment: Do you mean... do the iteration in my own code -- compare both x and y?

Comment: Exactly. You may also need to do an [epsilon comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356807/java-double-comparison-epsilon).

Comment: Comfirmed this post as answer and +1 for the two comments that helped me a lot. Thank you trashgod.