# How to javadoc accessors?

Tags: javadoc, getter-setter, accessor, mutators

Is there a way to write a javadoc comment for both an accessor and a mutator (getter/setter), to avoid duplicating information about the field underlying the method?

e.g.:

```
private float value;

/**
 * This value represents something.
 */
public float getValue () {
    return value;
}

/**
 * This value represents something.
 * @param    _value    A new value.
 */
public float setValue (float _value) {
    value = _value;
}
```

Seems inefficient and error-prone to duplicate information about the 'value' field in the javadocs for getter and setter....

Comment: There is some discussion on this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028967/simple-getter-setter-comments).

Comment: thanks beau.  figured this had been asked before but couldn't find it.  i voted to close my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the @see tag to point from the documentation of one method to the other like this:

```
@see # setValue (float)
```

Eclipse will help provide code completion for javadoc as well to make it easy to create the comments.

For details, @see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@see