# How to deal with JavaDoc comment repetition?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I was wondering what the best way of documenting this potential `Point` class is:

```
public class Point {
    /* the X coordinate of this point */
    private int x;
    /* the Y coordinate of this point */
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

My concrete concern lies with the repetition between the `x` and `y` attributes and their respective getters and setters, as well with the constructor arguments.

It's not that I'm developing a public API or anything of the likes, it's no problem for me to have a general comment regarding some variable and then having the getter and setter have just the same text, for instance. I'd just like to avoid comment repetition in my own internal code. Is there a way to tie `getX()` and the `int x` argument of the constructor to the `x` attribute, for instance?

Thanks

Comment: That is one of my issues with JavaDoc - there is no real support for macros, variables e.t.c. For example, there are some cases where I am implementing an interface and I would like to just add a couple of implementation-specific sentences to the JavaDoc inherited from the interface. Why should I have to copy over the whole thing?

Comment: @thkala, don't copy. Use `{@inheritDoc}` to have the inherited doc inserted at the appropriate place(s).

Comment: @devouredelysium, if this ain't for a public API then don't write any Javadoc at all. This class is so common and so trivial that it's easily understood by everyone. Javadoc in such a class would only clutter up source code. Actually, I wouldn't even write getters but use [@Getter](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) instead.

Comment: @MarcelStör: as you may imagine, I don't write Point classes for a living. This was obviously a simplified example to get people going.

Comment: @devouredelysium, no doubt about it - I thought so. However, one of your questions was "I was wondering what the best way of documenting this potential Point class is". My answer: don't. As for your specific question, I put it into a real SO answer.

Comment: @MarcelStör: `{@inheritDoc}` does not always work as expected - in my environment, for example, it does not inherit unchecked exceptions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Getter/Setter comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028967/simple-getter-setter-comments)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tie getX() and the int x argument of the constructor
>   to the x attribute, for instance?

No, not that I'm aware of. What *I* do:

- don't comment getters (or setters) at all
- if X needs contextual information and if it somehow represents (part of the) state of the class I document it in the class-level Javadoc only

Comment: what you describe is basically what i've been doing until now. i was naive enough to believe there was some more intelligent way to do things, tho.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious convention would be not writing JavaDoc comments for trivial getters.

Comment: I would have posted this as a comment as it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Sure. The trouble would be that then someone looking over my code could hover the mouse over the getter and be under the impression there's just no info available for that piece of data, which in some cases could be untrue. I generally don't put comments *everywhere*, so in many (most?) cases there may actually be no comments available.