# String with currency sign to float in Java

Tags: java, regex, type-conversion

i want to convert Strings (for example $2,480.00, $1.22) to float values (expecting results: 2480.00, 1.22).
Which way is best to do it? 
By loop, leaving in string digits and '.' or maybe with regex?

Comment: Assuming you know the currency signs, and the rest of the number follows the floating point spec you can just use `str.replaceAll("[$...]", "")` where the `...` is the other currency symbols.

Comment: You may have issues with number formats, (`.` vs `,`)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965831/how-to-parse-a-currency-amount-us-or-eu-to-float-value-in-java) is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Remove the first symbol, from the string; and then use Float.parseFloat("string") ...

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the string as float after removing non-number and non-dot characters:

```
float money = Float.parseFloat("$2,480.00".replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split your string and then use your numbers as you want :

```
        String str = "$2,480.00";
        str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

output :

```
[2, 480, 00]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using NumberFormat

```
String s = "$2,480.00";
float num = NumberFormat.getInstance()
        .parse(s.substring(1))
        .floatValue();
System.out.println(num);
```

## Assumptions

I have assumed the number **always** begins with a currency symbol

## Why not remove the `,`s and `.`s

If you do this you may have issues with international number formats, some of which change the meaning of dot and comma.

> In Canadian English, a period is used as the decimal marker, and a comma (or space) is used to separate three numerals. For example, 26,000 reads as twenty-six thousand.
>
> In French—and many other languages—a comma indicates the decimal, so 26,000 reads as twenty-six. That’s a huge difference from how an anglo would interpret it! The proper way to write twenty-six thousand in French is 26 000 or 26000.
> [source](http://www.syllabus.ca/en/didyouknow-en/writing-numbers-in-french-and-english/)