# Input double with dot instead of comma

Tags: java, decimal-point

I've got a input in my program expecting a double:

```
Scanner in_num = new Scanner(System.in);
double num1 = in_num.nextDouble();
```

but in the uploading system it throws exception `java.util.InputMismatchException` and I found out that it's because of the system writing a dot as a decimal point.

Is there a way in `Java` to take a number  with a dot as a decimal point instead of comma?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` only uses dot as a decimal point. Can you give an example?

Comment: Of course @KrzysztofKrasoń

Comment: This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257694/8041461

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch your Scanner into US Locale:

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
   double d = sc.nextDouble();
2. Use Double.parseDouble():

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(System.in));
   double d = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, just had to think a little bit. I've just taken a next `String` and parsed it to Double.

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(in_num.next());
```