# Float and Double for monetary values

Tags: java, floating-point, double, currency

I have experimented what is wrong with float and double types, in Java System.out.print(1-.6) prints .4 and the result is a bit unexpected (0.30000000000000004) in case of System.out.print(1-.7). It would be helpful if anyone is able to direct me towards some resources that explain WHY does it happen. I am assuming its not Java specific its something inherently wrong with these types.

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java gives the best recommendation.  Use BigDecimal.

Comment: I find it a source of constant amusement that, of the 1,123,061 questions currently on SO, 67% of them have to do with floating point inaccuracies :-)

Comment: thats good, I am not the only one then. Cheers for the links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 3):

The real types in Java are implementations of [IEEE754 single and double precision floating point notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008). These are approximations of real numbers rather than exact representations. Some real numbers like 0.8 cannot be represented accurately.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! I amgonna read that page, too many scary symbols though :(

Comment: Found this one quite helpful. http://ravisharda.blogspot.com/2010/09/floating-point-basics-made-easy.html

Answer (score 1):

As said Vincent the `float` and `double` types cannot store values that will not be represented as the sum of 2^-n values  (*n* size depends on the implementation).

Use the [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead.

Comment: Cheers, yeah I did read that thread about using BigDecimal for monetary calculations, was just curious about these types.