# Converting from String to BigDecimal to do math on currency

Tags: java, android, string, currency, bigdecimal

I am working on a project that requires some simple math to be performed on currency, however it arrives in the form of a String.  I am new to Java/Android so I am looking for help in converting from a String to a data type appropriate to this operation.  At first I thought Float was right but after reading elsewhere and introducing myself to the numbers class, it appears BigDecimal is correct.  Am I on the right track?  At this point I simply want to subtract the sum of payments from an initial invoice amount.  I get the feeling this code is simple but clumsy and I suspect I am missing a great deal about the nuances of working with currency.  How would you do it?  All advice warmly appreciated!

```
    // capture variables from sending activity
    String invoiceAmt = getIntent().getStringExtra("invoiceAmt");
    String paymentsSum = getIntent().getStringExtra("paymentsSum");

    // convert strings to BigD's 
    BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(invoiceAmt);
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(paymentsSum);

    // Do the math
    BigDecimal invDue = amt.subtract(sum);

    // insert the value (back to string) into textView
    TextView tvInvoiceDue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.InvoiceDue);
    tvInvoiceDue.setText(invDue.toString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is a fine approach.  So is using an `int` or a `long` to store cents.  I've heard some people like [Joda-Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) but I've never used it myself.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java).

In the code you posted, make sure the `String`s you are receiving don't have currency symbols in them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the link!  That is a thorough discussion.  As is often the case, I didn't know how best to ask the question in order to find the right answer... :)

Comment: Ugh... I am still too new to 'up arrow' your answer.  You deserve it, I hope someone more senior comes along and does it for me. Thanks again.