# Swiss and Argentinian currency fourth decimal digit rounding

Tags: rounding, currency, precision

When rounding amounts of currency using the algorithm for Swiss Francs, the second and third decimal digits are considered. If less than 26, they are rounded down to 0; else if less than 76, rounded down to 5; else the whole value is rounded up.

```
20.125  =>  20.10
20.143  =>  20.15
20.179  =>  20.20
```

What happens when the amount to be rounded has a greater decimal precision? Are all decimal digits after the third simply ignored (value is truncated), or is the value first rounded in some other way to three decimal digits first? As an example, consider truncation versus a "Math.round()" approach (less than 0.5 rounds down, else round up):

```
Truncation                      |  "Math.round"
=================================================================
Start        3 d.p.    Rounded  |  Start        3 d.p.    Rounded
=================================================================
20.1259  ->  20.125  =>  20.10  |  20.1259  ->  20.126  =>  20.15
20.1759  ->  20.175  =>  20.15  |  20.1759  ->  20.176  =>  20.20
```

As the above shows, these edge cases vary a great deal in the final result.

Argentinian currency rounding follows a similar model which just concerns itself with the third decimal digit. Although the rounded result may have two or three decimal places, the same principle applies; if the value to be rounded has four or more decimal digits, should the algorithm just truncate anything after the third digit or should it apply some other kind of intermediate rounding to get a three decimal place result first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If less than 26, they are rounded down to 0; else if less than 76, rounded down to 5; else the whole value is rounded up.

By this I would assume the "Truncation" method would be appropriate, since 0.0259XXXXX is less than 0.026

Comment: Yes, but I've paraphrased the description for brevity. There are numerous variations, including "0 < x < 26 => round down, 25 < x < 76 => round to .5, 75 < x => round up". That's one which leads to the ambiguity I've described. Wikipedia adds to the confusion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_rounding - and my original implementation was based off the following, though I believe its description is incorrect now: http://www.xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html

Comment: But surely, in any event you're still using the actual value to make the determination, not a value that's already been rounded by another method. You only want to round once. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably not, but this isn't something you want to get wrong. It's disturbing that I can find no definitive reference online or get a clear answer here, so it's clearly not such an easy question to answer. Truncation seems the most plausible answer, but also a rather arbitrary one; then again the whole algorithm seems pretty arbitrary, so perhaps I'm just allowing some vague notion of common sense to enter into the equation and, it seems, common sense has no place in finance :-D

Comment: I've worked in financial software for the last 13 years, and I can indeed confirm that there isn't much common sense going around ;-)

Comment: Well, 0.0259999... is only less than 0.026 if you have a finite number of 9's.