# Problems with double

Tags: java

I'm storing a number as a `double`. It works well with small numbers but if the `double` is 1000000 and I try to add 10 to it, it doesn't work but I can add 100 to it. If the `double` is 100000 and I try to add 1 to it, it doesn't work but I can add 10 to it.

Is this a problem with using a `double`? What format should I be using for up to a 9 digit number?

Edit: I'm doing calculations on the number and putting it in a 0.00 decimal format. It works on small numbers but not on big. It might have something to do with the other calculations. Just seeing if maybe double was the problem.

I run into problems when I take 1000001 / 100 and put in 0.00 decimal format. But 1000100 / 100 put into a 0.00 dec format works.

Comment: Are you using a `Double` (capital `D`) or a `double` (lowercase `d`)?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. In Java, `double` and `Double` are different things.

Comment: We can't wait to see how it "doesn't work" adding 1 to 1 million.

Comment: Hang on, your code isn't something like `double x = 1000001 / 100;`, is it?

Comment: I'm pulling a number stored as a String, I double x = Double.parseDouble(myString). then I dec.format(x) ... the string is in 0.00 decimal format. When it gets large then it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, just trying to eliminate the possible causes.

Comment: Wait a minute are you asking why 100.01 prints as 100.01 and 100.0001 prints as 100.00?

Comment: No. Anyways it seems like an issue with my sqldb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work", considering that it should:

```
System.out.println(1000000d + 10d); // 1000010.0
```

Cases where it wouldn't work are where there is a value that is more than about 15 digits from the most significant digit of the largest double involved:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(10, 18) + 10d - Math.pow(10, 18)); // 0.0
System.out.println(Math.pow(10, 17) + 10d - Math.pow(10, 17)); // 16.0
System.out.println(Math.pow(10, 16) + 10d - Math.pow(10, 16)); // 10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is how [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) works in general. (Although, as others pointed out, this should be well within the actual capabilities of `double`.) It loses more and more precision as the number is getting bigger. And even with small numbers, it isn't guaranteed to be precise. For small integers it is, as a general rule, but in practice, relying on the precision of floating point is a bad idea.

For integers, `long` should be good enough, 2<sup>63</sup>-1 is the biggest number you can store in it.

Otherwise `BigDecimal` is the answer. Not very convenient, but it is precise.

Judging by the update to your question, you want to store prices or something similar. In that case, you can either [use a library dedicated to currency arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java) (as there are often weird rules of rounding involved for example), or store pennies/cents in a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is absolutely large enough to store a 9-digit number, since the maximum value stored by a (signed) integer is `2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647` which has 10 digits.

If you need a larger range, use a `long`.

[Java Tutorial: Primitive Data Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

A double is actually able to hold that result. The most likely thing is probably that you're inspecting/printing out the number in such a way that appears like the number isn't different (could you post your test code?).

As a general rule of thumb, doubles give you ~16 digits of precision, and floats give you ~8 digits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of 9-digit number do you need to keep?   A `double` should have enough precision track 9 significant digits as would an `int`, but you need to know which type of number you need before you choose a type.  If you need real values (i.e., they have digits to the right of the decimal), then choose double.  If they are integers, choose `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your exact problem is very clear. Are you using integer arithmetic?  In which case you should expect an integer division to round down the answer.

```
int i = 1000001 / 100;
System.out.println(i);

double d = (double) 1000001 / 100;
System.out.println(d);
```

prints as expected

```
10000
10000.01
```

However, since you have't given a clear example of what does work and what you expect to happen, we are just guessing what your problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless, there is something wrong. It should be possible to (ab)use a double (which is in 64bit IEEE format in Java) as an 48-bit-or so integer. 48 bt should be enough to store 9 decimal digits.