# A better than BigDecimal type for prices in Java?

Tags: java

I need a financial type which will always keep numbers in X...X.YY format, even 20 digits, so I will get rid of rounding, formatting and other headache. Is there one?

Added: In other words I am looking for something like:

Financial f=1000.24;

f.setCurrency(USD);

System.out.print(f.toString()); -> $1'000.24

Comment: See [Representing Monetary Values in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java)

Comment: I think you are in danger of adding a requirement you are never going to need, adding over head to your application and development which will never benefit you. The US national debt is an estimate and it is only 16 digits long.  For this level of precision you can use `double` or `long`

Answer (score 4):

You can always keep financial data in longs, expressed in pennies.  But, as you say, there are various headaches involved in doing that, and the max value is, I'm thinking, 19 digits.  So BigDecimal would seem to be the way to go.

(Back when BitInteger/BigDecimal were being thought of I pushed for a packed decimal format that would have been lighter weight, but I couldn't get any support for it.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard Java type like that.

A BigInteger (in pennies) is probably the best choice out of the built-in types. (You don't need to worry about rounding that way). You can always make your own by wrapping BigInteger for convenience to add things like the currency marker and output in dollars.

Comment: Except you still have to worry about rounding with an integral type; for example, how do you divide $1.00 in three parts?  (Besides adding the spare penny to your own account =)

Comment: I honestly don't know the official rules for dividing $1 into three parts.

Comment: BigDecimal is the best choice because it can solve that problem. Money should always be handled in decimal.

Comment: @EJP How would BigDecimal solve the problem of splitting $1.00 evenly into three accounts?

Comment: @trutheality by providing a choice of rounding rules so that you could use the one that is appropriate to your domain. Banker's rounding (RoundindMode.HALF_EVEN) for example solves it nicely.

Comment: This results in one penny left over, though.