# Java best type to hold price

Tags: java, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Representing Monetary Values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java)

which java type is good to handle price value? and please tell my why ?

I dont know it is simply question :)

I only know that this type must be "safe". Because if we create shop applicatoion or somethink like that.

ps. I need **BEST PRACTICE**

and how it present in database ?

Comment: use 2 `int`s one for cents and one for dollars

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 27):

you should use [BigDecimal](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2001/jw-0601-cents.html) when dealing with currencies. Java's native floating point types suffer from the same precision issues as other languages, since some decimals cannot be accurately represented as floating point numbers. Even thought it's not java specific, [this is an excellent article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-01-04-practical-floating-point.html) which describes the complexities around representing decimal values as floating point numbers.

In general, transient values in your application should always use BigDecimal, only converting to a float when you must (for persistence, or displaying data to a user, etc).

Answer (score 7):

an integer (or long) for the smallest denomenator you care about (cents for USD and EUR)

this is because floating points on computers are inherently inaccurate for decimal values(0.1+0.2 != 0.3)

you only need to translate between cent and main dollar in the UI while the domain calculates everything in cents

Comment: `long` is the best, as long as you fit in. Which shouldn't be a problem, most of the times.

Comment: @zeller Unless you have insane hyper-inflation, in which case I would avoid those currencies.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use `BigDecimal` (and so does my company!).  I consider `float` or `double` bad suggestions because of the way [floating-point values are stored in the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and there is a possibility of loss of precision (which you certainly don't want when handling money).

Answer (score 3):

If you're building a financial system, I recommend you create or use your own Java class to represent monetary amounts.

As far as the data type to use to hold a monetary amount, long or BigDecimal.

Here's an example [Money class](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13) that shows the types of methods you need when working with monetary amounts.

Comment: And SQL representation of this class?

Answer (score 1):

If you use sensible rounding of your results `double` is works perfectly well and not only the fastest but the simplest to write. This can represent money up to $70 trillion without error. Don't use `float` as this can only represent up to about $10,000 without error.

If you don't know what sensible rounding to use, `BigDecimal` or `long` cents could be a better choice.

Comment: What would sensible rounding be in this case?

Comment: @lovrodoe if you really don't know then 8 decimal places is probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.