# How to return a double with two decimal places?

Tags: java, double

I want to return a double with 2 decimal places (i.e. 123.00). The following are part of the codes. The output is always 123.0. How to get a two decimal places?

```
public static double getPrice(){

    double price = Double.valueOf(showInputDialog("Stock's price : "));

    DecimalFormat rounded = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

    double newPrice = Double.valueOf(rounded.format(price));
    System.out.println(newPrice);

    return newPrice;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, if you're working with currency, you'd better *not* use floating points.

Comment: There is such thing as a 'double with two decimal places'. They don't have decimal places at all: they have binary places. If you want decimal places, you must work in a decimal radix, i.e. BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the return type of your function is `double`, the short answer is "you can't".

Many numbers that have no more than two decimal digits cannot be represented exactly as `double`. One common example is `0.1`. The `double` that's nearest to it is `0.100000000000000005551115...`

No matter how much rounding you do, you wouldn't be able to get exactly `0.1`.

As far as your options go, you could:

1. accept the rounding issues associated with using `double`;
2. return an `int` (i.e. the rounded value multiplied by 100);
3. return a `String`;
4. return a `BigDecimal`.

In particular, if you're representing monetary amounts, using `double` is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: so if it's for monetary amounts, which is the best to use? BigDecimal?

Comment: @mellissa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java

Comment: So, I've tried with bigdecimal and now the trouble is to get two decimal places even when it is a whole number like 123 still prints out 123.00 (with .00 behind). how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When formatting, you're making a string from a double. Don't convert your formatted string to a double again :

```
String formattedPrice = rounded.format(price);
System.out.println(formattedPrice); // prints 123.00 or 123,00, depending on your locale
```

A [double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) keeps a numerical value following IEEE754, it doesn't keep any formatting information and it's only as precise as the IEEE754 double precision allows. If you need to keep a rendering information like the number of digits after the comma, you need something else, like [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: You can't. The `double` format doesn't keep this information.