# how do you make both arrays correlate in java?

Tags: java, arrays

i want to be able to correlate these two arrays so that when i start with user input i can access the name and the price

```
public class fastFood
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
   {
    //array for prices and order
     double[] prices= new double[]{"5.79", "6.79", "4.59", "5.39", "6.59", "7.29", "6.09", "5.69"};
     String[] menu= new String[8];
     menu[0]="Whopper Meal";
     menu[1]="Double Whopper Meal";
     menu[2]="Chipotle Whopper Meal";
     menu[3]="Whopper Jr. Meal";
     menu[4]="BK Double Stacker Meal";
     menu[5]="Premium Chicken Sandwhich (Crispy or Grilled) Meal";
     menu[6]="Chipotle Chicken Sandwhich (Crispy or Grilled) Meal";
     menu[7]="OriginalChicken Sandwich Meal";


  }
 }
```

Comment: Your question makes me feel hungry. :) Use a Map<String, Double>

Answer (score 17):

Few mistakes in your code:

1. You are storing strings in a double array? (I don't know why. That wouldn't even compile.)
2. Never ever store price as double or float (a blunder). `float` and `double` don't have enough precision to store all the floating point numbers accurately. For e.g., 0.1 can not be stored accurately in `double` or `float`. With monetory value, you can't take that fact lightly. You should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead which is arbitrary-precision signed decimal number.
3. Instead of maintaining two different arrays, you should maintain a `Map<String, BigDecimal>` mapping from items to their prices.
4. Then to further refactor your code, you should create a class `Item` storing all those attributes, like this:

   ```
   class Item {
       private String name;
       private BigDecimal price;

       // constructors, getters, setters
   }
   ```

   and then, maintain a list of items:

   ```
   List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
   ```

**See also:**

- [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/1679863)
- [Representing Monetary Values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285680/1679863)

Comment: Are you mention that prices should be stored as BigDecimal because of exchange reasons (Dollar -> Euro f.e.) ? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @SteveBenett. No, that's a different issue. double and floats don't have enough precision to represent all floating point numbers exactly. And with monetory values, accuracy can not be played with.

Comment: @rohitjain You should add that explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.util.HashMap` (or some other `java.util.Map` implementation).

```
Map<String, Double> menu = new HashMap<String, Double>();
menu.put("Whopper Meal", 5.79d);
//..and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that this is a poor way of implementing this, you could easily correlate these by accessing them with the same index.  As long as they were entered in the correct order, this will work.

```
double price = prices[2];
String menuItem = menu[2];

System.out.println(String.format("%s costs $%.2d",menuItem, price);
```

This should print "Chipotle Whopper Meal costs $4.59".

Depending on what you are doing this for, you really should look into creating objects to represent these menu items.  Example:

```
public class MenuItem
{
     public double price;
     public String name;

     public MenuItem(String name, double price)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.price = price;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
         return String.format("name: %s cost: $%.2d",name,cost);
     }
}
```

Now in your code, you could do the following:

```
List<MenuItem> menuItems = Arrays.asList(
    new MenuItem("Big Mac",4.23);
    new MenuItem("Quater Pounder",3.23);
    new MenuItem("Chicken Sandwich",5.63);
);

for(MenuItem m : menuItems)
{
    System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

This will print out every item in menuItems.  The name and price are automatically correlated since they are contained together as attributes in each instance of a MenuItem object.